# Can't figure out how to add two CGFloats?

Tags: swift

I'm getting this error "Cannot invoke '+' wit an argument list of type '(CGFloat, CGFloat)' when using this Swift code.

```
var added = CGFloat(gestureRecognizer.view?.center.y) + CGFloat(translation.y)
```

What am I doing wrong. I have two floats and I want to add them together.

Answer (score 3):

This line here:

```
gestureRecognizer.view?.center.y
```

Can be thought of as an expression that returns a `CGFloat?` optional. If `view` is `nil`, it returns `nil`. If `view` has a value, it drills in. And `CGFloat(nil)` is a compile error.

```
var added = CGFloat(gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y) + CGFloat(translation.y)
//                                        ^ ! instead of ?
```

You really want to unwrap it here. Because if `view` is `nil` you pass `nil` to `CGFloat()` which isn't gonna be cool. But you do have to think about what might happen when `view` is `nil`.

Perhaps that will never happen in the flow of your program, I don't know. But if it is `nil` that will cause a runtime crash.